# How to log return value after async/await?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, async-await

Below have I pasted in PoC code, where I have removed lots of lines, but it shows the problem/question I am facing.

`createPost()` returns a "post number" in the `ret` variable. I don't need the "post number for anything else than logging it.

With the current implementation, I have to define `ret` outside of the `while` loop, and since sequential code is run before asynchronous code in the NodeJS event loop, I expect the logging will be executed before `createPost()`, which is not what I want.

**Question**

Is it possible to only log `ret` when `createPost()` have been executed?

```
module.exports = async (p) => {
  let ret = 0;

  try {

    while (true) {

      switch (x) {
        case 1:
          isOk = await getStatusCode({ ... });
          break
        case 2:
          isOk = await getString({ ... });
          break
        default:
          throw "";
      };

    ret = await createPost(p);
    appLogger.info(`Created post: ${ret}`);   // I don't need 'ret' for anything else than logging it

  } catch (error) {
    appLogger.error(error);
  }
}
```

**createPost.js**

```
const axios = require('axios');

module.exports = async (c) => {
  try {
    const r = await axios({ ... });
    return r.data.key;
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(JSON.stringify(error.response.data, null, 2));
  };

};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...and since sequential code is run before asynchronous code in the NodeJS event loop, I expect the logging will be executed before createPost(), which is not what I want.

All of the code in an `async` function after the first `await` is asynchronous, not synchronous. In your code, the `appLogger.info` call won't happen until `createPost` has **finished** its work (asynchronously).

So there's no need to declare `ret` outside the loop (and even if the above weren't true, that wouldn't really help), you can just do it inline, see `***` comments:

```
module.exports = async (p) => {
  // *** No `ret` here

  try {

    while (true) {

      switch (x) {
        case 1:
          isOk = await getStatusCode({ ... });
          break
        case 2:
          isOk = await getString({ ... });
          break
        default:
          throw "";
      };

    const ret = await createPost(p); // *** Declare it here
    appLogger.info(`Created post: ${ret}`);

  } catch (error) {
    appLogger.error(error);
  }
}
```

The code waits, asynchronously, at the `await` and only continues when `createPost` is done.

Here's a simplified example:

```js
const randomDelay = () => new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(Math.random() * 300) + 500));
});

async function doSomethingElse() {
    await randomDelay();
}

async function createPost(i) {
    await randomDelay();
    return i * 2;
}

async function example(max) {
    console.log("Starting (this log is synchronous)");
    for (let i = 0; i < max; ++i) {
        await doSomethingElse();
        const ret = await createPost(i);
        console.log(`i = ${i}, ret = ${ret}`);
    }
    console.log("All done");
}

console.log("Calling example");
example(5)
.then(() => {
    console.log("example promise fulfilled");
})
.catch(error => {
    console.error("example promise rejected", error);
});
console.log("Done calling example, it's running asynchronously");
```

---

**Technically**, you don't need `ret` at all, this would also work:

```
appLogger.info(`Created post: ${await createPost(p)}`);
```

but if it were me, I'd keep it as shown in the first code block above. It's easier to debug.

Comment: When you write "is asynchronous, not synchronous", then I don't understand "appLogger.info call won't happen until createPost has finished its work (asynchronously)." Or do you mean that after the first `await` the remaining will execute sequential in the asynchronous queue? If that is correct, then I could in principle removal all `await` except the first on in each `async` function?

Comment: @SandraSchlichting - Both, really, but your thing about removing subsequent `await`s isn't correct. You need the `await` to make the function logic wait until the promise settles. If you do `a = await x()`, the function code waits for promise returned by `x` to settle and (if it's fulfilled) it assigns the fulfillment value to `a` and continues. But if you just do `a = x()`, the promise object itself is assigned to `a` and the code doesn't wait for the promise to settle. (That's true regardless of whether there's a previous `await `in the function.)

Comment: FWIW, I go into detail about promises in Chapter 8 and `async` functions in Chapter 9 of my recent book *JavaScript: The New Toys*. If you're interested, there are links in my profile.

Comment: That is exactly the kind of book I have been looking for!

Comment: Ok, makes sense about `await` and returned promise. So all code inside an `async` function is run sequential in the asynchronous queue?

Comment: @SandraSchlichting - Basically. There isn't really an "async queue" per se, it's just a task queue (well, there are two levels, tasks and microtasks), other things are queued as well. But the purpose of `async` functions is to let you write the flow of your logic using the usual `for`, `if`, etc. rather than callbacks, with `await` to say "wait for a promise here before continuing." Happy coding! :-)